# HTML onsubmit event is not calling the JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, html, sijax

I have two buttons in my form for calling two JavaScript functions. The first button works good in its `onclick` event calling the `payroll()` function successfully but the second button is of type submit and it never calls the `send()` function on form submission. I don't know why this issue occurs.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
<head>
    <title>hr page</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript"
    src="/static/js/sijax/sijax.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    {{ g.sijax.get_js()|safe }}</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{url_for('static', filename='styles/signupcss.css')}}">

    <script type="text/javascript" >
function payroll() {
        var basic=document.forms["salary"]["bsalary"].value;
        var empid=document.forms["salary"]["empid"].value;
       var ta,hra,da,pf,netsalary,grosssalary;
         if (empid == ""||basic == "") {
        alert("Employee ID and Salary details must be filled out");
        return false;
        }
        if(isNaN(basic))
        {alert("Salary must be in Numbers");
        return false;
        }
       hra=basic*40/100;
        da=basic*15/100;
        pf=basic*12/100;
        basic=parseInt(basic);
        hra=parseInt(hra);
        da=parseInt(da);
        grosssalary=basic + hra + da;
        ta=basic*6.2/100;
        netsalary=grosssalary-ta;



        document.getElementById("hra").innerHTML=hra;
        document.getElementById("ta").innerHTML=ta;
        document.getElementById("da").innerHTML=da;
        document.getElementById("netsalary").innerHTML=netsalary;
        document.getElementById("pf").innerHTML=pf;


        document.getElementById("grosssalary").innerHTML=grosssalary;
         window.alert("HI"+grosssalary);
        return true;


    }
     function send()
    {
        var id = document.forms['salary']['empid'].value;
        var basic =  document.forms['salary']['bsalary'].value;
        var hra =  document.forms['salary']['hra'].value;
        var da =  document.forms['salary']['da'].value;
        var ta =  document.forms['salary']['ta'].value;
        var pf =  document.forms['salary']['pf'].value;
        var gross_sal =  document.forms['salary']['grosssalary'].value;
        window.alert("HI"+gross_sal);
        var net_sal =  document.forms['salary']['netsalary'].value;
        Sijax.request('send',[id, basic, hra, ta, da, pf, gross_sal, net_sal]);

    }

</script>
</head>
<body style="font-family:Lato">
    <div style="padding-left:5%;padding-top:0.2%;height:1%;width:100%;background-color:#11557c">
    <h2>Welcome to HR Department</h2><br>
    </div>
<div style="margin-left:15%" >
    <h2>Name</h2>
<form id="salary" name="salary" style="margin-top: 2%" method="post" onsubmit="return send()" >
    <label id = "empid">Employee ID</label><br>
    <input type = "text" name = "empid" placeholder = "Employee ID" /><br><br>
    <label id = "bsalary">Basic Salary</label><br>
    <input type = "text" name = "bsalary" placeholder = "Basic salary" /><br><br>
    <input type="button" value="Calculate" onclick="return payroll()"><br><br>

    <label for ="hra">House Rent Allowance(HRA)</label>
    <p id="hra" name="hra"></p><br>
    <label for ="ta">Travel Allowance(TA)</label>
    <p id="ta" name="ta"></p><br>
    <label for ="da"> Dearness Allowance(DA)</label>
    <p id="da" name="da"></p><br>
    <label for ="netsalary">Net Salary</label>
    <p id="netsalary" name="netsalary"></p><br>
    <label for ="pf">Provident Fund(PF)</label>
    <p id="pf" name ="pf"></p><br>
    <label for ="grosssalary">Gross Salary</label>
    <p id="grosssalary" name="grosssalary"></p><br><br>
    <input type="submit"  value="Upload Salary">
</form>
    </div>




</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You have several errors on your code.

Comment: Can you please explain how it affects my form submission on a sijax request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't act with `<p>` elements like as a form-elements. You may create a respective `<input type="hidden">` elements and fill them in `payroll()`, or get values by .innerHtml on paragraphs.

P.S. You have actually a TypeError exception, calling undeclared form elements like `document.forms['salary']['grosssalary']` and so on.

Comment: Is that the reason why my sijax request is not been detected?

Answer (score 0):

okay, quick fix, since you are using python flask library Sijax for ajax and therefore jQuery, you can alter your javascript `send` function like this:

```
function send(e){
        e.preventDefault(); //it is as good as returning 
                            //false from the function in all cases

        var id = document.forms['salary']['empid'].value;
        ...
 }
```

and change your `onsubmit` handler declaration like this:

```
<form id="salary" name="salary" style="margin-top: 2%" method="post" 
          onsubmit="return send(event)" >
```

please note that when you stop the event chain propagation, you will have to do a manual submission of the form.
So, you can modify your send function to do `.preventDefault` based on your custom criterias, otherwise, let the form submit

Comment: I need to know whether the sijax request in my send method has been processed or not because my view function does not detect any sijax request to it

Answer (score 0):

Your code actually works, if you're running this code as a snippet here in stack overflow, Form submission is actually blocked by default. Try running your code in `codepen`. I tried it and it's actually working.
http://codepen.io/jhonix22/pen/VPZagb

Answer (score 0):

Check this out. It is nowhere close to a perfect solution but I think it helps. You can not access the paragraphs as if you would the form input elements. Im not entirely sure what Sijax thing is. I believe it is just a normal AJAX HTTP thing with some sort of CSRF security filters.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>hr page</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript"
            src="/static/js/sijax/sijax.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        {
            {
                g.sijax.get_js() | safe
            }
        }</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{url_for('static', filename='styles/signupcss.css')}}">

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function payroll() {
            var basic = document.forms["salary"]["bsalary"].value;
            var empid = document.forms["salary"]["empid"].value;
            var ta, hra, da, pf, netsalary, grosssalary;
            if (empid == "" || basic == "") {
                alert("Employee ID and Salary details must be filled out");
                return false;
            }
            if (isNaN(basic)) {
                alert("Salary must be in Numbers");
                return false;
            }
            hra = basic * 40 / 100;
            da = basic * 15 / 100;
            pf = basic * 12 / 100;
            basic = parseInt(basic);
            hra = parseInt(hra);
            da = parseInt(da);
            grosssalary = basic + hra + da;
            ta = basic * 6.2 / 100;
            netsalary = grosssalary - ta;

            document.getElementById("hra").innerHTML = hra;
            document.getElementById("ta").innerHTML = ta;
            document.getElementById("da").innerHTML = da;
            document.getElementById("netsalary").innerHTML = netsalary;
            document.getElementById("pf").innerHTML = pf;

            document.getElementById("grosssalary").innerHTML = grosssalary;
            window.alert("HI" + grosssalary);
            return true;
        }

        function send() {
            var id = document.forms['salary']['empid'].value;
            var basic = document.forms['salary']['bsalary'].value;

            var hra = document.getElementById('hra').innerHTML;
            var da = document.getElementById('da').innerHTML;
            var ta = document.getElementById('ta').innerHTML;
            var pf = document.getElementById('pf').innerHTML;
            var gross_sal = document.getElementById('grosssalary').innerHTML;
            window.alert("HI" + gross_sal);
            var net_sal = document.getElementById('netsalary').innerHTML;

            // I think you are missing something here.
            Sijax.request('send', [id, basic, hra, ta, da, pf, gross_sal, net_sal]);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body style="font-family:Lato">
<div style="padding-left:5%;padding-top:0.2%;height:1%;width:100%;background-color:#11557c">
    <h2>Welcome to HR Department</h2><br>
</div>
<div style="margin-left:15%">
    <h2>Name</h2>
    <form id="salary" name="salary" style="margin-top: 2%" method="post" onsubmit="return false">
        <label id="empid">Employee ID</label><br>
        <input type="text" name="empid" placeholder="Employee ID"/><br><br>
        <label id="bsalary">Basic Salary</label><br>
        <input type="text" name="bsalary" placeholder="Basic salary"/><br><br>
        <input type="button" value="Calculate" onclick="return payroll()"><br><br>

        <label for="hra">House Rent Allowance(HRA)</label><br>
        <p id="hra" readonly name="hra"></p>
        <label for="ta">Travel Allowance(TA)</label><br>
        <p id="ta" readonly name="ta"></p>
        <label for="da"> Dearness Allowance(DA)</label><br>
        <p id="da" readonly name="da"></p>
        <label for="netsalary">Net Salary</label><br>
        <p id="netsalary" readonly name="netsalary"></p>
        <label for="pf">Provident Fund(PF)</label><br>
        <p id="pf" readonly name="pf"></p>
        <label for="grosssalary">Gross Salary</label><br>
        <p id="grosssalary" readonly name="grosssalary"></p><br>
        <input type="button" onclick="send()" value="Upload Salary">
    </form>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```